# Laravel policy not running on update/delete model

Tags: laravel, roles, policies

I'm trying to make this policy stuff work, and i have followed the documentation. But it doesn't seem like the policy code is not even run.

I have `Role` model. And i created `RolePolicy`. The thing i want to do in the policy is to ensure that the role with the ID of 1 never-ever gets updated or deleted.

My `RolePolicy` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class RolePolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Role  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(Role $role)
    {
        return $role->id === 1
        ? Response::deny('Cannot change super-admin role')
        : Response::allow();
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Role  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(Role $role)
    {
        return $role->id === 1
        ? Response::deny('Cannot delete super-admin role')
        : Response::allow();
    }
}
```

I even tried to do a `dd()` inside both delete and update method in the policy, but when i try to delete/update the model with the ID of 1, nothing happens. The `dd` wont run, nor will the response in the current code above.

I have registered the policy in the `AuthServiceProvider` where i also have this gate to give the super-admin all the permissions.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Role;
use App\Policies\RolePolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Role::class => RolePolicy::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // Implicitly grant "Super Admin" role all permissions
        // This works in the app by using gate-related functions like auth()->user->can() and @can()
        Gate::before(function($user, $ability) {
            return $user->hasRole('super-admin') ? true : null;
        });
    }
}
```

Here is also my `RoleController` method for updating the `Role` model:

```
/**
 * Edit role
 *
 * @param Edit $request
 * @param Role $role
 * @return void
 */
public function postEdit(Edit $request, Role $role)
{
    # Validation checks happens in the FormRequest
    # Session flash also happens in FormRequest

    # Update model
    $role->update([
        'name' => $request->name
    ]);

    # Sync permissions
    $permissions = Permission::whereIn('name', $request->input('permissions', []))->get();
    $role->syncPermissions($permissions);

    return redirect(route('dashboard.roles.edit.get', ['role' => $role->id]))->with('success', 'Changes saved');
}
```

Does the gate i use to give all permissions have anything to do with the policy not running? Or what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Gate::before` method in the `AuthServiceProvider` was the problem. Removed this and rewrote the permissions, policies and some gates to get the error messages from the policies.

Decided to give the role `super-admin` the permission `*` and check for this with `$user->can()` and middleware `.....->middlware('can:*')` and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

The `User` model that is included with your Laravel application includes two helpful methods for authorizing actions: `can` and `cant`. The `can` method receives the action you wish to authorize and the relevant model. For example, let's determine if a user is authorized to update a given `Role` model:

```
if ($user->can('update', $role)) {
    //
}
```

If a policy is registered for the given model, the `can` method will automatically call the appropriate policy and return the boolean result. If no policy is registered for the model, the `can` method will attempt to call the Closure based Gate matching the given action name.

**Via Controller Helpers**

In addition to helpful methods provided to the `User` model, Laravel provides a helpful `authorize` method to any of your controllers which extend the `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` base class. Like the `can` method, this method accepts the name of the action you wish to authorize and the relevant model. If the action is not authorized, the `authorize` method will throw an `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException`, which the default Laravel exception handler will convert to an HTTP response with a `403` status code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the given role.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  role  $role
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $role);

        // The current user can update the role...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so after trying this now, i still can't get it to work. I tried to see if i could use `$user->can('update', $role)` in the controller, and i still can update it for some reason. Same with `$this->authorize(...)`, same result. It's as if the policy is just ignored.